# How should IIS-hosted ASP.Net-based systems be deployed to Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-service-fabric, guest-executable

Azure Service Fabric's documentation has ample examples of deploying and hosting ASP.Net Core on Azure Service Fabric. Nowhere is the deployment of IIS-hosted apps to be found.

How could one deploy ASP.Net sites and WCF services as guest executables on an Azure Service Fabric cluster as simply as deploying them to an Azure App Service instance?

Answer (score 4):

We have successfully done this using Docker. For example, we use the following docker image as base:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
```

Note that Microsoft no longer hosts these images on docker hub.

Here is an example of rather complicated one. As you can see, we build the image from a pre-compiled ASP.NET application, install some IIS modules and even pull an installer for a compression module's extension.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

COPY OurSite c:/OurSite

# Enable IIS's Static Content, Static Content Compression and App Init modules
# Download & Install IIS compression extension (providing Brotli)
# Setting "staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency" attribute on "HttpCompression" tag in applicationHost.config (that's the only place we can set that attr)
# Remove Default Web Site
# Register a new site
# Set following properties on the Application Pool:
#   - "Start Mode" to "AlwaysRunning" to ensure w3wp process always starts
#   - "Idle Timeout" to 0 ensuring w3wp process doesn't get terminated due to inactivity.
# Recycle Application Pool
RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationInit ; \
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-StaticContent ; \
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpCompressionStatic ; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/1/C/61CC0718-ED0E-4351-BC54-46495EBF5CC3/iiscompression_amd64.msi \
        -OutFile c:\iiscompression_amd64.msi ; \
    Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '-i', 'c:\iiscompression_amd64.msi', '/quiet', '/passive' -NoNewWindow -Wait ; \
    Remove-Item c:\iiscompression_amd64.msi -Force ; \
    $ConfigSection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.webServer/httpCompression" ; \
    Set-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $ConfigSection -AttributeName "staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency" -AttributeValue True ; \
    Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site' ; \
    New-Website -Name 'OurSite' -Port 80 -PhysicalPath 'c:\OurSite' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5' ; \
    Import-Module WebAdministration ; \
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\AppPools\.NET v4.5' -Name 'startMode' -Value 'AlwaysRunning' ; \
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\Sites\OurSite' -Name 'applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled' -Value 'true' ; \
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\AppPools\.NET v4.5' -Name 'processModel.idleTimeout' -Value '00:00:00' ; \
    Restart-WebAppPool '.NET v4.5'

VOLUME c:\\data

EXPOSE 80
```

We then host these images in a secured Container Registry, Create a Service Fabric project (in Visual Studio) which gives us the template for the required manifests using which we'll deploy as many containers as we need. At the deployment time, Service Fabric reads your manifest, pulls and caches the docker image and creates the containers accordingly. It goes without saying that your manifests will have to contain information about the registry and associated credentials.

**Side note**: never use the "latest" tag of your images in the manifests, because, as mentioned, Service Fabric caches images. Also, remember to configure your cluster to clean up old images. Otherwise, depending on your application, you might run outta space quickly.

**Update**: Storing docker images in Aure ACR, one can use Managed Service Identity and avoid storing the registry's credentials in the manifests. The Identity assigned to the cluster's underlying VM Scale Sets can be given access to ACR to download docker images during deployment. This ensures the credentials are not seen by anyone having access to the SF's explorer dashboard (and one doesn't have to worry about encrypting the secrets in manifest).

Comment: This is the correct answer, and would be the only way of getting IIS to run within a SF cluster.  Another approach that could work is running IIS Express as a guest executable.  I haven't tried this, but in theory it could work.  No idea if this would be a good idea or not.  SF is designed for reliable services or guest executables, not running Windows Services.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I don't know whether IIS Express is a production ready application server.

Comment: Yea, it's probably an absolutely awful idea..  Not recommended, 0 stars..

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK , Afraid that for ASP.Net web site, we have to use conventional approach to scale up/scale out.

Migrating WCF to ServiceFabric comes with quandary verbal expression of scaling Monolithic WCF Accommodations. To scale the application, Only Horizontal scaling will be get done by increment number of Web Server with load balancing in front of it.

To surmount this issue microservices architectural approach is the best one to opt for. We can breakdown Single WCF application to several microservices hosting as WCF application.

One of approach is to Move this WCF to service fabric (Distributed System Platform) as stateless service and scale the service by engendering various instance of services within service fabric cluster.

If you want to do minimal changes to move your application to distributed environment ,can [host using WCF communication stateless service](https://technologyjourney4it.wordpress.com/2017/03/31/migrate-and-host-wcf-in-service-fabric/) in service fabric.

Check the below doc for further reference:

https://amoghnatu.net/2017/07/03/creating-wcf-service-hosted-in-azure-service-fabric-over-https-with-basic-authentication/

https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.WcfCalc

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1342/create-wcf-service-azure-service-fabric

Hope it helps.

Comment: We're looking for solutions that wouldn't involve refactoring the application's state management subsystem.